# Why does my c++ code keep printing a random number?

Tags: c++, debugging

Hi I need help with this code. It keeps on printing "ur input:32765" and the number keeps changing. I read a question on stack overflow and it said it wasn't initialized, whatever that means. Can someone help with whats wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int x;
cout << "ur input:";
cin >> x;
cout << "" << x;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/djkExKXBUOz4Y86L).  What compiler and compiler settings are you using?  What input are you using?

Comment: is it always 32765?

Comment: what input do you type?

Comment: Not reproducible. What compiler you are using and what input you are giving ?

Comment: not always 32765. It keeps changing.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
if (cin >> x){
    cout << "" << x;
} else {
    cout << "bad input";
}
```

otherwise a read of an unintialised `x` could arise if the `cin` fails in C++03 or earlier. That can happen if there are not data on the stream that can be read into an `int` type.

Comment: FWIW, starting in C++11, any invalid read attempt will zero out that passed in variable.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Indeed it does - that's one for the pub. It's a shame that most schools seem to use a pre C++11 compiler. The jump to C++11 was such a quantum leap.

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you SO much everyone :) it worked. So. Yea. Thanks.